# Drupal Page manager: Can I provide a variant in my module?

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-ctools

I have a module that provides a number of pages to the Page Manager module using `hook_default_page_manager_pages()`. This works out fine.
But now I would also like to provide a variant for the system included `node/%node page`. But I can't find any hooks for providing variants.

My problem is, that I can not create my own page to overwrite node/%node, since this is already provided by the Page Manager module itself, so only way I can create pages that takes over the normal node view, is to provide a variant (from my understanding).
But how can I do this programmatically?
I can see that it's possible to export the variant, and therefore I guess that it would also be possible to provide it through a hook?

Is this possible in any way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found what I was looking for.

To provide variants for pages build with page manager in code, in your module file call hook_ctools_plugin_api(), to let Page Manager know, that it should listen to your module:

```
/**
 * Implement hook_ctools_plugin_api().
 *
 * Tells ctools, page manager and panels, that we have a template ready
 */
function mtvideo_ctools_plugin_api($module, $api) {
  // @todo -- this example should explain how to put it in a different file.
  if ($module == 'panels_mini' && $api == 'panels_default') {
    return array('version' => 1);
  }
  if ($module == 'page_manager' && $api == 'pages_default') {
    return array('version' => 1);
  }
}
```

Now create a new file in your module root folder called MODULE_NAME.pages_default.inc.
In this file you can now include the following functions:

```
hook_default_page_manager_pages()
/**
 * If you want to put an entire page including its variants in code.
 * With the export module from ctools, you can export your whole page to code.
 * Paste that into this function.
 * (Be aware that the export gives you $page, but you need to return an array,
 * So let the function return array('page name' => $page);
 */
```

and/or

```
hook_default_page_manager_handlers()
/**
 * This will provide a variant of an existing page, e.g. a variant of the system
 * page node/%node
 * Again, use the export function in Page Manager to export the needed code,
 * and paste that into the body of this function.
 * The export gives you $handler, but again you want to return an array, so use:
 * return array('handler name' => $handler);
 *
 * Notice, that if you export a complete page, it will include your variants.
 * So this function is only to provide variants of e.g. system pages or pages
 * added by other modules.
 */
```

I hope this helps another in need one day :o)
Only thing I have left to discover is how my module programmatically can enable the node/%node page in Page Manager.
If any one has a clue feel free to share it with me :)

Comment: Did you ever discover a way to enable node/%node in the page manager? In my own module, I can't seem to get it to work without importing the variant(s), which seems counter-productive if the variant is meant to be stored in code.

Comment: I provided a patch to an outstanding issue here, which resolved things for me: http://drupal.org/node/1287626

Comment: Hi Michael, yes - you can enable node/%node by setting a variable as it is handled by variables: variable_set('page_manager_node_view_disabled', 0); (Notice that the variable name is _disabled, so set the value to 0 to enable the variant)

Comment: It is also possible to use Features to export a variant: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/225861/27068 . The Features module makes under the hood the same changes you describe in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if I've misunderstood but I think there are two ways you could attack this:

Firstly you could implement [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7) to override the page callback for the path:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['page callback'] = 'mymodule_node_page_callback';
}

function mymodule_node_page_callback($node) {
  // Build up the content and return
}
```

In this case you'd need to make sure that in the `system` table your module has a higher value in the `weight` column than the Page Manager module (so your hook will be called later on and will have the final say as it were).

Secondly you could implement [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) and just override the content altogether:

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full') {
    $node->content = array();
    $node->content['title'] = array('#markup' => '<h1>' . $node->title . '</h1>';

    // Build up the rest of the content
  }
}
```

In this case you'll need to build up the content as a render array (see the [`drupal_render()` function](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_render/7)).

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi Clive. This won't provide a variant of the page in page manager, which is my goal. By providing a variant of the page in page manager, my admin users will be able to change the page through the Page Manager UI.